# Conflicting types for 'Graph' error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error saying 'conflicting types for 'Graph' for the following code, but I'm not sure what the issue is, as Graph is declared before it is used anywhere. Anyone know what the issue is?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define __USE_BSD // make prototype for strdup visible
#include <string.h>

typedef struct linkedlist { // linked list of ints (for use in Node)
  int index;
  struct linkedlist *next;
} List;

typedef struct { // a Node of a Graph
  char *name;
  List *outlist; // adjacency list
  int outdegree; // length of outlist
  int indegree; // length of inlist
  int dfsnum;
  //double pagerank_score; //not needed for this exercise
} Node;

typedef struct {
  int MaxSize;
  Node *table;
} Graph;

// use to check result of strdup, malloc etc.
extern void check (void *memory, char *message);

extern int initialize_graph (Graph *mygraph, int MaxSize);
extern int insert_graph_node (Graph *mygraph, int n, char *name);
extern int insert_graph_link (Graph *mygraph, int source, int target);
extern int read_graph (Graph *mygraph, char *filename);
extern void print_graph (Graph *mygraph);
```

Comment: Does your compiler tell you something like "previous definition was here:..."?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes it says previous definition of 'Graph' was on line 24

Comment: This does not produce any errors for me. Is this your entire code?

Comment: @n.m. I don't get any errors in GCC but using CDT MinGW I get these errors in Eclipse.

Comment: Okay, line 24 is the line shown. On what line (number, and what does it [and the few before and after] contain) do you get the error?

Comment: Let me ask the question a bit differently. **Is this your entire code?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think CDT MinGW has an extended C lib which already has a variable name reserved which is called "Graph", have you tried renaming your struct? This might be the case though i have never worked with CDT MinGW before